# python irc bot - not returning full list of channels

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I copied an already made irc script and modified it a bit.

```
# Import some necessary libraries.
import socket 
channelList = []

# Some basic variables used to configure the bot        
server = "irc.freenode.net" # Server
channel = "#kiwiirc-default" # Channel
botnick = "Mybot" # Your bots nick


def ping(): # This is our first function! It will respond to server Pings.
  ircsock.send("PONG :pingis\n")  

def sendmsg(chan , msg): # This is the send message function, it simply sends messages to the channel.
  ircsock.send("PRIVMSG "+ chan +" :"+ msg +"\n")

def joinchan(chan): # This function is used to join channels.
  ircsock.send("JOIN "+ chan +"\n")

ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ircsock.connect((server, 6667)) # Here we connect to the server using the port 6667
ircsock.send("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" :This bot is a result of a tutoral covered on http://shellium.org/wiki.\n") # user authentication
ircsock.send("NICK "+ botnick +"\n") # here we actually assign the nick to the bot

joinchan(channel) # Join the channel using the functions we previously defined
send = True
while 1: # Be careful with these! it might send you to an infinite loop
  ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048) # receive data from the server
  ircmsg = ircmsg.strip('\n\r') # removing any unnecessary linebreaks.
  #print ircmsg # Here we print what's coming from the server

  if send:
    ircsock.send('LIST\r\n')
    send = False
  x = ircmsg.split()
  x = [val for i, val in enumerate(x) if '#' in val]
  channelList += x
  print len(channelList)

  if 'PING :' in ircmsg: # if the server pings us then we've got to respond!
    ping()
raw_input()
```

It sends the LIST to the server and the server will send back the information. I then add it to a channelList and print out the length. 
When I type /list into my irc client, it returns "49400 channels found"

The final channelList length *should* be 49400, but it is always 18,000ish (forgot the exact number)

I'm using https://kiwiirc.com/client

Comment: Are you sure the server actually sends all data?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it but I feel it's an error on my part.

Comment: Check with a real IRC client